# Find address of a cell containing a formula, using text value in the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a cell line containing the word "ok", this is my code:

```
Dim findValue As Long
findValue = Sheets("STOCKS").Range("E:E").Find("ok").Row
```

The problem is that the cell containing the word "ok", for example E5, is filled by a formula taking the value of another cell in another sheet. So I am getting the following error:

> execution error 91 : object variable or bloc variable with not defined
>   (I have translated the message from French to English.)

I think it's because the cell contains the formula and not the real value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really think the formula is the problem you can add

```
lookin:=xlValues
```

as a parameter to your find function so that it reads:

```
findValue = Sheets("STOCKS").Range("E:E").Find("ok", lookin:=xlValues).Row
```

You will also get this error if the value you're looking for isn't found.  You can check for this with this code.

```
Dim findValue As Long
Dim r As Range

Set r = Sheets("STOCKS").Range("E:E").Find("ok", LookIn:=xlValues)

If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
    findvalue = -1
Else
    findvalue = r.Row
End If
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, the looking parameter is perfect.